# Filtro sin funcionar en Oracle SQL Dev

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy intentando filtrar una columna `PK_FECHA` definida como `NUMBER(6,0)` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE PK_FECHA = 202010
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve 0 resultados. Por otro lado, si hago la misma sentencia pero transformando `PK_FECHA` a `NUMBER` si que me hace el filtro de forma correcta.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE TO_NUMBER(PK_FECHA) = 202010
```

No entiendo porqué está pasando. El campo está definido como un `NUMBER`, **no** debería ser necesario hacer la conversión.

Alguna idea?

Comment: En MySQL no existe un tipo de dato `NUMBER()`, ¿quizá te refieres a `NUMERIC()`? Tampoco existe `TO_NUMBER()`. ¿Seguro que usas MySQL?

Comment: @A.Cedano, lo siento. Me confundí con la etiqueta. No estoy usando MySQL.

Comment: Pues dinos qué SGBD estás usando y coloca la etiqueta del mismo en la pregunta. Hay variaciones a veces entre uno y otro.

Comment: Estoy usando SQL Developer de Oracle. Post modificado.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de INSERT? Y, ¿podrías decirnos por qué no declaraste esa columna del tipo `DATE`?